# Register Client Script in a specific place

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a master page file and i want to register a weather widget dynamically by selecting a city.

When i register the script block on the page it's seen like this .Can i register it on a specific place like div or etc ?

http://prntscr.com/2bjxil

This is my code :

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(someType, "clientScript", string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='http://www.havadurumux.com/api.php?dcr=%23eeeeee&apr=%23eeeeee&icr=%23eeeeee&ikap=%23eeeeee&fr=%23000000&br=%23eeeeee&dr=%233570a9&wt=tekli&cityurl={0}'></script>", ddlSehir.SelectedValue));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="LtrWeatherWidget" />` at the place where the weather widget should be located at.

Then in your code behind just do

```
LtrWeatherWidget.Text = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='http://www.havadurumux.com/api.php?dcr=%23eeeeee&apr=%23eeeeee&icr=%23eeeeee&ikap=%23eeeeee&fr=%23000000&br=%23eeeeee&dr=%233570a9&wt=tekli&cityurl={0}'></script>", ddlSehir.SelectedValue);
```